# How does 平均 differ from 均匀?

Tags: grammar, loanwords

I already knew that 平均 means "average", 均匀 means "even" or "evenly distributed". But how to distiguish these two phrases? Can you give me some examples? Thanks a lot!

Comment: iciba has plenty 爱词霸有很多

Answer (score 8):

1. if i have 10 apples , i give you 5 and keep the another 5 myself , it called "平均";
   [image]
2. Here "picture 1" is called “均匀”, while picture 2 is called “不均匀”.

   [image: “均匀”] [picture 1]

   [image: “不均匀”] [picture 2]

Comment: @FernWhite If this answers your question, please consider accepting it. (Click on the √ sign below the voting buttons.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
Case 1:
```

The average age of gamers is 22
游戏玩家的平均年龄是22
You cannot use 均匀 here but only 平均

```
Case 2:
```

This painting's color is evenly distributed
这幅画的颜色分布均匀
You cannot use 平均 here but only 均匀

```
Conclusion:
```

I will say "average" is one of the result / statistic of a distribution, where "evenly distributed" is one of the many ways to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have 2 apples, your brother has 4, so, you guys 平均 have (2+4)/2=3
but it is not 均匀, if you have 3, your brother has 3 too, then it is 均匀.